# Layer-list center item not getting full height

Tags: android-layout, android-imageview, android-drawable

I have a layer-list, with a oval at the start, a line in the middle and a rectangle at the end; booth oval and rectangle have 8dpx8dp and the line I've been trying using no height or 32dp of height x 8dp width

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:gravity="top"
            android:bottom="40dp"
            android:top="0dp">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
                <size android:width="8dp" android:height="8dp"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:top="0dp"
            android:bottom="0dp"
            >
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:toDegrees="90">
            <shape
                android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="#ff00ff"
                    android:dashWidth="1dp"
                    android:dashGap="2dp"
                    />
                <size android:width="8dp"
                    />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
        </item>
        <item
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:top="40dp"
            android:bottom="0dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
                <size android:width="8dp" android:height="8dp"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>

</layer-list>
```

This is the ImageView where i'm displaying it.

```
<ImageView
                    android:layout_width="8dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_large"
                    android:src="@drawable/place_selector_left_image"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    />
```

but It don't work as expected the line don't take the full height I assigned to it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when I created the line is horizontal so it can only take the width of the container, and when I rotated it it wasnt' the height I wanted, I added left and right offset to the item.
This is my final code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="40dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
            <size
                android:width="8dp"
                android:height="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:top="8dp"
        android:right="-32dp"
        android:left="-32dp">
        <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:toDegrees="90">
            <shape
                android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="#ff00ff"
                    android:dashWidth="1dp"
                    android:dashGap="2dp" />
                <size android:width="8dp"
                    android:height="32dp"
                    />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:top="40dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
            <size
                android:width="8dp"
                android:height="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```